# Arrays (Solidity)

Tags: solidity, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to make this function work in such a way that when you compile and interact with the hasDups function, it will print either TRUE or FALSE, depending on which array you wish to call. What else am I missing in my code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract ReturnArrayBool {

    uint256[] arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
    uint256[] arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,5];
    
    function hasDups(uint256[] memory arr) public pure returns(bool){

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            uint256 digit = arr[i];

            for(uint256 j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if(arr[j] == digit) {
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I tried that code and sent an array without duplicates and it returned false, then I sent an array with duplicates and it returned true, so it is working alright.

Comment: For example, I am trying to set it up in such a way where if I choose to index arr1 with the hardcoded values of [1,2,3,4,5] then I should get a return value of FALSE and TRUE for arr2. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically be able to select a state array to work on, you could put it in a `mapping` with a key to identify it:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract ReturnArrayBool {

    mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) public hardCodedArrays;

    constructor() {
        hardCodedArrays[1] = [1,2,3,4,5];
        hardCodedArrays[2] = [1,2,3,4,5,5];
    }
    
    function hasDups(uint256 arrayIndex) public view returns(bool){
        uint256[] memory arr = hardCodedArrays[arrayIndex];
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            uint256 digit = arr[i];

            for(uint256 j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if(arr[j] == digit) {
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }

    function addElements(uint256 toArray, uint256 element) public {
        hardCodedArrays[toArray].push(element);
    }

}
```

I put a simple example. You could dynamically add elements. You could write logic to remove elements, search for elements, etc.

Notice that I used a `1` as the key of the first array, and a `2` as the key of the second array.

You could then call like from Remix like:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you so much